# What does `BytesPrimL` represent?

Tags: haskell, literals, template-haskell

I can figure out what most literals represent with `ppr`, e.g. `WordPrimL 7` = `7##`, `CharPrimL 'x'` = `'x'#`, etc. The only constructor I *can't* figure out is `BytesPrimL`:

```hs
λ> bytes <- mallocForeignPtrArray @Word8 5
λ> let bytesLit = LitE (BytesPrimL (mkBytes bytes 0 5)
λ> ppr bytesLit
"<binary data>"
```

So, what code would generate an `Exp` with a `BytesPrimL` constructor? What is it supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ghci> bytes <- mallocForeignPtrArray @Word8 5
ghci> let bytesLit = LitE (BytesPrimL (mkBytes bytes 0 5))
ghci> :t $(pure bytesLit)
$(pure bytesLit) :: GHC.Prim.Addr#
```

### Incorrect, see edit below:

I'm pretty sure there is no Haskell code that corresponds to that. Instead, this is piggy-backing on the way GHC already compiles string literals to allow you to embed arbitrary binary data in the executable efficiently.

### Edit:

```
ghci> :t "foo"#
"foo"# :: GHC.Prim.Addr#
```

It turns out there is a literal for that, when `-XMagicHash` is enabled.